# What is the difference between ContentProvider and FileProvider in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

What is the difference between `ContentProvider` and `FileProvider`?. I want received `URI` image when use camera .

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? `FileProvider` is a subclass of `ContentProvider` which is dealing with files. Not sure why you need to use `SQLite` so can't really help with anything other than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ContentProvider is a component that enables you to securely share any kind of data, FileProvider is used specifically for sharing the app's internal files. The FileProvider class is part of the v4 Support Library so make sure to include it in your project

Comment: but isn't *everything* a file?